# how to use split in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, split

im get date for ng-model like that

> Thu May 21 2015 18:47:07 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

but it show me in console `"TypeError: date.split is not a function`" how to fix it?

```
   $scope.test = function(date) {
    console.log(date);
    $scope.d = (date.split(' ')[0]);
    $scope.m = (date.split(' ')[1]);
    $scope.y = (date.split(' ')[2]);
    $scope.dd = (date.split(' ')[3]);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `date` is not a String, it's a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object instance. So you can't use split on it. In order to use it you might want to convert it to String first. For example like his:

```
$scope.test = function(date) {
    date = date.toString();
    $scope.d = (date.split(' ')[0]);
    $scope.m = (date.split(' ')[1]);
    $scope.y = (date.split(' ')[2]);
    $scope.dd = (date.split(' ')[3]);    
};
```

When you console log it `console.log(date);` it calls `toString` automatically that's why it looked like a string for you.

Another thing, you really should not use split to extract data. Use methods of the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, like `getMonth`, `.getFullYear`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the date variable you get passed is not a string, but a [Javascript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) which has no `split()` method. You could go on and convert it to a string that you could split:

```
$scope.d = (date.toString().split(' ')[0]);
```

Which would work but not be very efficient, because the date would be composed to a string and then parsed again. Better would be using the properties of the date object itself:

```
$scope.d = date.getDate();
$scope.m = date.getMonth() + 1;
$scope.y = date.getFullYear();
```

and so on...

Find all the useable methods on the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).
Even better would be keeping the date itself as it is and just using the date properties where you need them in the view, for example:

```
<div class="myDate">Year: {{date.getFullYear()}}
```